# How do I restore the 'tasks' Gmail gadget?

Tags: gmail, google, google-tasks

I accidentally undocked then closed it, and I don't know how to restore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click on the location switcher above the left navigation (if you are in your inbox, it will say "Gmail ▼") and select "Tasks."

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna Google Tasks Gadget in Gmail content area, try Gmail Tasks gadget:

http://www.google.com/ig/directory?url=google-tasks-gadget-canvas-edition.googlecode.com/files/google_tasks_gadget_for_gmail.v.kbcm.xml

Comment: Obsolete hyperlink?